# Angular: Download HTML from server and print

Tags: html, angular, typescript, iframe, printing

In my application, I have some views that should be printable. You can think of them as reports. I generate the HTML on the server-side.

When a user clicks the "print" button, I dispatch the API call, retrieve the rendered html as text, put it into an `<iframe>` and call `print()` on the resulting window.

On chrome and firefox (desktop), this works (more or less...)

But the behavior on chrome mobile (android) is *very* strange. The API call is dispatched correctly, and the "system" print modal openes, but instead of the iframe content, the "parent" page content is displayed for printing (the one containing the "print" button).

It is, as if the iframe I am calling `print()` on, isn't the correct window on mobile devices. I have checked with the remote developer console on android, there is no error or other message that could give me any hints.

If it helps, this is the code I use in my service to generate the iframe with the printable content:

```
return this._api.printEntity(entity).pipe(
  tap(data => {
    const iframe: HTMLIFrameElement = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    const printWin: Window = iframe.contentWindow!;
    printWin.document.write(data);
          
    setTimeout(() => {
      printWin.focus();
      printWin.print();
      printWin.close();
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    }, 1000);
  })
);
```

As you may notive, I used a *very* large timeout, to give the iframe enough time to load style files and images in the generated report. I have tried using `printWin.onload` etc, but I couldn't get it to work.

I find it hard to believe, that such a simple task seems to be so cumbersome, is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until someone comes up with a better solution, here is how I solved it.
There are actually multiple steps to it, I guess the combination of them all helped me solve it:

- Make sure that the downloaded HTML file does not contain any links (styles, images) that have to be loaded. This (at least I think it does) ensured that the IFrame is ready immediately, so that I don't have to mess around with timeouts until all requests go through.
- Download the HTML *as file*. By downloading it, converting it to a file, creating an object url from that and setting this as the iframe `src`, I was able to print on mobile browsers. I simply base64 encoded everything, from font to image. This has the added benefit of much more portability. Especially, if your images/data is only accessible for authenticated users.
- Use `onafterprint` to remove the iframe from the DOM *after* printing. Otherwise the print screen was blank.

Here is how my print method looks now, no issues whatsoever:

```js
public printEntity(entity: TEntity): Observable<void> {
      return this._http.get('yourUrlHere', {responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'}).pipe(
        tap((res: any) => {
          const blob: Blob =  new Blob([res.body], {type: 'text/html'});
          const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const iframe: HTMLIFrameElement = document.createElement('iframe');
          iframe.src = fileURL;
          document.body.appendChild(iframe);

          const printWin: Window = iframe.contentWindow!;
          printWin.print();
          printWin.onafterprint = () => { printWin.close(); document.body.removeChild(iframe); };
          
        }),
        switchMap(_ => of()),
      );
```